# Foundation.MediaQuery.current in a loop (first iteration always shows nothing, next are always correct)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I use `Foundation.MediaQuery.current` to determine current breakpoint. Every time I call `console.log(Foundation.MediaQuery.current)` for the first time **(n=0)** I get nothing.

For all next calls **(n>0)** I always get correct breakpoint, let's say `large`.

This is my function:

```
_calculateLimit = function () {
    var postsInjectedCount = container.find('.post-appended').length;

    console.log(Foundation.MediaQuery.current);

    if (Foundation.MediaQuery.current === 'large') { // gives nothing on first iteration :/
        return postsInjectedCount % 3 !== 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }

    return postsInjectedCount % 2 !== 0 ? 1 : 2;
},
```

Below picture shows a screen from my Chrome Dev Tools.

[image]

Helpful info 1: There is no difference in terms of business logic between first call and next calls.

Helpful info 2: I use Foundation For Sites `~6.2.1`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you adding this code, after Foundation init code?

Comment: Hi @ShoaibIqbal, you were right. I did call parent function before initiating Foundation. Please write your comment as an answer, so I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running the code before Foundation has initialized. It is a good practice to put the init code at the top of JavaScript file.

Comment: Thanks Shoaib. That helped me. I was indeed calling my function before initiating Foundation. However I left that in footer, I just moved my method after `$(document).foundation();` and now everything works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will see it better if put the console.log at the end of the function. So try it and just tell the results.

It will clarify where the error is.